Decrypting ecryptfs files recovered using photorec
(There was a similar very old question here but I wasn't sure that I should / could bump that and my case is slightly different)
I am tasked with recovering some information that a user deleted by mistake. Using photorec I was able to recover a large number of files in the format fnnnnnnn.eCryptfs where n is a digit. There's a fair chance that one of the files has the needed information in it. Now I've been given the whole system which is still all present and fine, along with the password to log in and decrypt the file system. This isn't the case of a deleted partition or anything else - just hitting delete on some files he shouldn't have.
I'll confess after reading through other answers (including the one linked above) for about an hour this is beyond me. Or at least without a lot more of a deep dive. Everything seems to assume you're trying to decrypt an entire (/home/user) directory structure whereas I am trying to decrypt a file I know neither the original name of nor its location. Actually, I do know the name and location of the target file for what it's worth, but not which of the numerous files that would be.
I used ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase and got what I think is the actual encryption key itself. I believe I'm in the fortunate situation of theoretically having everything I need to recover the information, assuming it's amongst the many that photorec recovered. But what on Earth the steps I should follow to do this I'm struggling with. I can probably bash script my way through testing each of the files if I can figure out how to actually decrypt one but everything I find is about ".private" directories and ".secret" this and mounting a whole partition elsewhere. Whilst I just want to go through decrypting a bunch of recovered files on the already decrypted and mounted still existing home partition.
I'm hoping this is simple for someone who knows more about ecryptfs than I do. :)
Oh, for what it's worth the distribution is Mint Debian Edition.

Do NOT boot this machine! Image the drives first!!

After taking backups, what happens if you run sudo ecryptfs-recover-private (see the man page for more info)? This article might help.

See this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1442055

@Hydranix I'm afraid it was already booted up multiple times and used though I've recovered a large number of deleted files from it. I honestly hadn't actually realised it was an encrypted home directory until I saw all the files were .encryptfs. I don't think photorec can restore them to their locations, it just places everything in a place I picked for it (in this case a thumbdrive). I'm reading through the other question you linked, thank you. There are two answers there, are you directing me at the first or the second? The first seems to suggest mounting the directory without (contd.)

(contd.) decrypting and restoring the files as their raw encrypted files. Is the theory that I can then mount the directory normally with decryption and they'll be decrypted along with everything else? Or should I be looking at answer #2 and just ecryptfs-recover-private the entire directory of recovered files? I'd be fine with that if it works - I'm just directed to find some specific information which I could easily grep through for if I just had the decrypted files.
Thank you for your help.

There was never anything posted as an explicit answer for me to mark as accepted but fwiw, I was eventually able to recover the data using ecryptfs-recover-private as @harrymc suggested. I had to do a lot of grepping through the resulting giant heap of decrypted files that lacked any directory structure but I got it. Thanks.
